# Shortening long expressions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to create a function handle to the function:

```
f = @(x) (x-1)*(x-2)*...*(x-50);
```

How can I do this in MATLAB without typing all 50 terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
y = prod((x-[1:50]))
```

Or if you want an anonymous function:

```
f = @(x) ( prod((x-[1:50])) )
```

By the way, it might not be faster than @Chris solution (which is good, and I upvoted it), because of Matlab JIT-Accelerator.

Comment: `f=@(x) prod(x-[1:50])` is working and `f=@(x) prod(x-1:50)` is producing something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a function. For example,

```
function y = myfunc(x, n)
    y = 1.;
    for i = 1:n
        y = y*(x-i);
    end
end
```

The function you defined is basically the [product of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation), which are trivially written as `for` loops.

In your case you want to compute this result for 50 terms, so you could just use `y = myfunc(x, 50)` or, if you want this to be a function handle, you could define

```
f = @(x) myfunc(x, 50);
```